# Admin Grid issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I have created an admin grid, but it is not showing the edit form.
My files :

> 1.`Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule.php`

```
<?php
namespace Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml;
class Skipredirectmodule extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container
{
    protected function _construct()
    {           
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_skipredirectmodule';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Stw\Skipredirectmodule';
        $this->_headerText = __('Custom Settings');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Custom Page'); 
        parent::_construct();           
    }
}
```

> 2. `Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Grid.php`

```
<?php
namespace Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule;
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    protected $moduleManager;
    protected $_setsFactory;
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_type;
    protected $_status;
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $_visibility;
    protected $_websiteFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
        \Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Model\ResourceModel\Skipredirectmodule\Collection $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setId('skipredirectmoduleGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('skipredirectmodule_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);           
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        try{                                
            $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->load();           
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            parent::_prepareCollection();             
            return $this;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
        }
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'skipredirectmodule_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'skipredirectmodule_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'skipredirectmodule_countryid',
            [
                'header' => __('Title'),
                'index' => 'skipredirectmodule_countryid',
                'class' => 'column2'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'status',
            [
                'header' => __('Status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'class' => 'column3',
                'type'      => 'options',
                'options'   => array(
                      1 => 'Enabled',
                      2 => 'Disabled',
          ),
            ]
        );
            $this->addColumn(
            'action',
            [
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'index' => 'action',
                'class' => 'column1',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => __('Edit'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id',
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('skipredirectmodule_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('skipredirectmodule');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            array(
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('skipredirectmodule/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            )
        );
        return $this;
    }
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'skipredirectmodule/*/edit',
            ['id' => $row->getId()]
        );
    }
}
```

> 3.`Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit.php`

```
<?php
namespace Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule;
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Stw_Skipredirectmodule';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_skipredirectmodule';
        parent::_construct();
        $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Setting'));
        $this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Delete Setting'));
        $this->buttonList->add(
            'saveandcontinue',
            array(
                'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
                'class' => 'save',
                'data_attribute' => array(
                    'mage-init' => array('button' => array('event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'))
                )
            ),
            -100
        );
        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('block_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'hello_content');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'hello_content');
                }
            }
        ";
    }
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('skipredirectmodule_data')->getId()) {
            return __("Edit Item '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('skipredirectmodule_data')->getTitle()));
        } else {
            return __('Admin Panel');
        }
    }
}
```

> 4.`Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit\Tabs.php`

```
<?php
namespace Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit;
class Tabs extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs
{
    protected function _construct()
    {    
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('skipredirectmodule_skipredirectmodule_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Custom Module'));
    }
}
```

> 5.`Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit\Form.php`

```
<?php
namespace Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit;
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    protected $_customerAccountService;
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            array(
                'data' => array(
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                )
            )
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

> 6.`Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit\Tab\Form.php`

```
    <?php
namespace Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit\Tab;
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    protected $_systemStore;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('skipredirectmodule_skipredirectmodule');
        $isElementDisabled = false;
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('page_');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('skipredirectmodule_form', array('legend' => __('Skip Redirect Settings')));
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array('name' => 'id'));
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'column1',
            'text',
            array(
                'name' => 'column1',
                'label' => __('column 1'),
                'title' => __('column 1'),
            )
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'column2',
            'text',
            array(
                'name' => 'column2',
                'label' => __('column 2'),
                'title' => __('column 2'),
            )
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'column3',
            'text',
            array(
                'name' => 'column3',
                'label' => __('column3'),
                'title' => __('column3'),
            )
        );        
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('status', $isElementDisabled ? '2' : '1');
        }
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();   
    }
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('General');
    }
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('General');
    }
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
    protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
    }
}
```

> 7.`Stw\Skipredirectmodule\view\adminhtml\layout\skipredirectmodule_skipredirectmodule_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="skipredirectmodule_grid"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule" name="admin.skipredirectmodule.grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 8.`Stw\Skipredirectmodule\view\adminhtml\layout\skipredirectmodule_skipredirectmodule_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit" name="skipredirectmodule_skipredirectmodule_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
         <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit\Tabs" name="skipredirectmodule_skipredirectmodule_edit_tabs">
                <block class="Stw\Skipredirectmodule\Block\Adminhtml\Skipredirectmodule\Edit\Tab\Form" name="skipredirectmodule_skipredirectmodule_edit_tab_form"/>
                 <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">form_section</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">stw_skipredirectmodule_edit_tab_form</argument>
                </action>
                <!--CedAddTab-->
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image: page screenshot]

Please help me to solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the cache.I was refering https://github.com/cedcommerce/magento-2-sample-module for creating the grid. But I can't find out what is the issue.

Comment: Please help me, I am stuck here.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and **`var\log\system.log`** told me that what was the actual issue. I did a spelling mistake in dependency injection of a class in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing controller NewAction. 
After that, add in execute()

```
$this->_forward('edit');
```

Btw, you should use Magento UI component :)